# How to reduce load on server when we need to run the same queries multiple times with a slight change of condition

Tags: mysql, performance, server, load

**EDIT**

is it better to combine all the queries in 1 single select like `select (select...) as q1, (select...) as q2`

**END EDIT**

I need to run the same following queries for each month of the year.

The difference between each query is just by adding a `group by` or removing a sing condition.

**First Query**: I need to count the total visits done

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
from 
    visit 
where 
    visit_status='Active' 
AND 

    month(visit.date_of_visit)=month(:selectedDate)
AND
    year(visit.date_of_visit)=year(:selectedDate)
```

of course `:selectedDate` will be set by binding values in PHP.

**Second Query**: is about counting number of patients (not visits), and that would be done by just adding `group by visit.patient_id`

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
from 
    visit 
where 
    visit_status='Active' 
    AND 

        month(visit.date_of_visit)=month(:selectedDate)
    AND
        year(visit.date_of_visit)=year(:selectedDate)
group by visit.patient_id
```

And then I will use `rowCount` to get the result as the returned value are rows due to `group by`.

The same queries should be repeated but now without the date, which means counting since the first time data has been registered on the system:

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
from 
    visit 
where 
    visit_status='Active' 

group by visit.patient_id
```

I am not having an errors using the following method, but is there a better way to do this and reduce the load on server by minimizing the number of queries ?

Comment: You could do the grouping on the client

Comment: @schlonzo is it better to combine all the queries in 1 single select like `select (select...) as q1, (select...) as q2`?

Comment: You are inconsistent on the use of `GROUP BY`.  Was that a typo?

Comment: No. Without the group by I will get the number of visits done per month (lets say 210 visits) and with the group by I will get the exact number of patients (190 patients)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select COUNT(distinct (visit.patient_id))  from visit where  visit_status='Active'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `patient_id` is not ever `NULL`, you should write the query as:

```
select count(distinct v.patient_id)
from visit v
where v.visit_status = 'Active' and
      v.date_of_visit >= :selectedDate - interval (1 - day(:selectedDate)) day and
      v.date_of_visit < last_day(:selectedDate) + interval 1 day;
```

This is a much better way to write the query, particularly if you care about performance:

- This can make use of an index on `visit(visit_status, date_of_visit, patient_id)`.
- You are only returning what you really want -- which is the number of unique patients.
- You can remove the `where` condition on date to get all dates.